# metamorph tags interfering with table cell layout

Tags: css, ember.js

I'm building a table cell using two bound ember.js views on data.   When I do that, ember.js inserts its metamorph tags such that it can update the view later.

```
<td>
<a data-ember-action="14">
  <div id="ember2065" class="ember-view">
    <script id="metamorph-102-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      02/04/2012
    <script id="metamorph-102-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  </div> 
    @ 
  <div id="ember2072" class="ember-view">
    <script id="metamorph-103-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      $61.81
    <script id="metamorph-103-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  </div>
</a>
</td>
```

These tags cause the date and the price below to line wrap within the cell.   Is there a CSS styling that I can apply to these tags to make them not effect line breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your stylesheet to prevent line breaks from ember views:

```
div .ember-view {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Don't feel it's a good solution, as you are setting this to _any_ view... You should at least refine scope.

Comment: Please consider my samples below, and do not hesitate to ask further ways to render as needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depend on your full case. It seems to me that using views is superfluous here, but maybe I am missing some information.

Here are some working samples: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/QCbGN/

Maybe providing more context would help to have better sample.